# Javascript to dynamically insert plugins and code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to provide my users with a single `<script>` tag that will add some plugins to the page and execute some javascript code.  I'm providing my users with a code snippet like this, and asking them to add it anywhere within the body of their website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//my-domain/code?s=1a2b3c4d&t=faq&cb=1408412749" async></script>
```

In the response, I have the following Javascript code:

```
//add jquery to page
var script  = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://my-domain/assets/js/jquery.min.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);

//move jquery to our own namespace
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerText = "var SB = {};SB.$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to add Jquery to the page, and then namespace it in case Jquery already exists.  The problem is that when the code executes, I'm receiving this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

So, clearly jQuery is not loaded yet when the namespacing code executes, but I don't understand why. Shouldn't jQuery be defined at this point?

Comment: What happens if you `append` to the `head` rather than the `body`?

Comment: Just tried. Same issue. It's strange. Watching the network activity, I can see that the call to load jQuery is "pending" while the response from the original script tag is executing. It's only after the response is fully processed that I can then correctly see the jQuery variable is defined. Is it possible that dynamically inserted external scripts can't actually be used until the script that inserted them finishes executing?

Comment: The `async` call could be causing that exact scenario. If you remove the `async` does it work properly?

Comment: Since this is a very specific implementation, a very specific implementation could be to add `var SB = {};SB.$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);` directly to the end of `jQuery.min.js`.

Comment: `async` is not the issue based on my tests. I actually just discovered the `script.onload` method, and using that seems to work. I just put the second block of code inside script.onload = function{}. Do you see any issues with that?

Comment: Nope, that should work nicely. You're basically telling it do not perform any actions on the script until it's fully loaded (or eliminating the asynchronicity of that particular script). I still might stick it in the `head` section just as a CYA but that's your call.

Comment: FYI.. jQuery has a `.getScript()` with a callback that serves the same purpose but it's a moot point when it's the jQuery source that you're loading. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `script.onload` function seems to have solved the problem:

```
//add jquery to page
var script  = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://my-domain/assets/js/jquery.min.js';
script.onload = function(){
    //move jquery to our own namespace
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerText = "var SB = {};SB.$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
document.body.appendChild(script);
```